# How to use a Google Doc Apps Script OAuth token to do Firebase IDP login?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, oauth

I am building a Google Docs add-on.

I specifically need to access Firebase resources (eg. Firestore) as the **user** that is logged in to Google Docs and hence I need to have a Firebase ID token to access Firebase and  **not** with "admin" access to Firebase using a service account, which most Firebase docs refer to when describing using a Google OAuth token directly.

In the add-on JS code I do this to get the current users OAuth token:

```
var authToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
console.log("Auth TOK:"+authToken);
```

as described in the [docs for the sample code from Google](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples/NoLibrary). This seems to work and gives me something that looks like a valid token.

I then try to exchange that for a Firebase ID token, for now I'm just trying this using curl:

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"postBody":"id_token=[GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN]&providerId=[google.com]","requestUri":"[http://localhost]","returnIdpCredential":true,"returnSecureToken":true}'
```

the above is taken from [the Firebase REST API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential).

Its also basically the same as what is mentioned in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113181/how-to-get-the-firebase-id-token-from-google-oauth-token) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63059395/85472).

BUT unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and I get an error response back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Invalid Idp Response: access_token audience is not for this project",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Invalid Idp Response: access_token audience is not for this project",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And in my Firebase project I have Google set as one of my sign-in providers.

As far as I know I have used the required scopes in my App Script `appscript.json`:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["profile", "email", "openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase" ,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Would anyone have any idea of what I'm missing here? I guess there is something needed to tell Firebase to allow using Google OAuth tokens with my Firebase project?

Comment: Have you tried this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-via-oauth-2-access-token) and see if it works?

Comment: The first three values of outhScopes doesn't look to be valid (ref. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)

Comment: @OctaviaSima thanks for the link, but that article is about using OAuth with Firebase for admin access, ie. with service accounts, where as I specifically need to be able to access Firebase as the logged in user accessing the Google Doc. I'll update my question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Rubén no turns out they are required, without those scopes I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Failed to fetch resource from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo, http status: 401, http response: {\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 401,\n    \"message\": \"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.\",\n    \"status\": \"UNAUTHENTICATED\"\n  }\n}\n",
...
```

Comment: It turns out that the error was due to the Google Doc Apps Script being in a **different** Google Cloud Project to the Firebase project. Once they are both in the same GCP it actually does work. I figured it out from seeing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969462/85472